# $c_0[0,1]$ in $C(K)$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $K=[0,1]\times \{0,1\}$ be endowed with the topology arising from the lexicographic order on it. It is known that $K$ is compact, Hausdorff, first-countable and perfectly normal. Furthermore, the space $c_0[0,1]$ is a quotient of $C(K)$. Is $c_0[0,1]$ a (complemented) subspace of $C(K)$?

Comment: In Fabian-Habala et all the space $K$ is called "two arrow space", see [p.634](http://books.google.com/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA634). You can find there also the result about the quotient, which is mentioned in the question.

Comment: Thanks. They prove that the dual $C(K)^*$ is weak*-separable, but the dual of $c_0[0,1]^*$ is not, hence $c_0[0,1]$ does not embed into $C(K)$. Is that right?

Answer (score 2):

Double arrow space $K$ is [hereditarily Lindelof](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/the-lexicographic-order-and-the-double-arrow-space/), so [it satisfies](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2012/09/05/product-of-spaces-with-countable-chain-condition/) countable chain condition. By [theorem 14.26 (ii)](http://books.google.ru/books?id=5BDX2NNsqR4C&pg=PA628&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q&f=false) the space $C(K)$ can not contain $c_0(\Gamma)$, for uncountable $\Gamma$ and in particular $[0,1]$ since it is also uncountable.